# Significato di "indetta" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

In questa [notizia di Euronews](https://it.euronews.com/2020/06/02/george-floyd-anche-in-europa-migliaia-in-strada-contro-razzismo-e-violenza-delle-autorita), ho letto  (grassetto mio):

> A Milano, il flashmob ha seguito le regole del distanziamento sociale e si è tenuto davanti al consolato americano. Stessa location a Napoli per la manifestazione **indetta** sabato prossimo [...].

La mia domanda è sul significato di "indetta" che appare in questo brano. Ho cercato il verbo "indettare" in alcuni dizionari, tra i quali il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/indettare) e il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00000800.jpg), ma non mi sembra che nessuna delle accezioni corrisponda all'uso che se ne fa nel brano sopra citato. Ricercando "manifestazione indetta" su Google, però, ne trovo parecchie occorrenze.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "indetta" in riferimento a una manifestazione?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il verbo è *[indire](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/indire/)*. Ah, i verbi irregolari! È un composto di *dire*, quindi *indico* (parola piana), *indicevo*, *indissi*, *indica*, *indetto*.  Il participio passato di *indettare* è *indettato*.

> Ordinare o disporre che sia preparata, organizzata e iniziata con una certa solennità una manifestazione di pubblico interesse.

Comment: Ah, sempre cado in questo tipo di trappole!